# Работа за границей

Tags: работа

Добрый день!

Подскажите пожалуйста, на каких ресурсах можно искать IT работу за границей, или поделитесь опытом, как сами переехали. Ещё хотелось бы узнать субъективные оценки о том, что более востребованно, куда лучше "рваться". Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вначале идете на [linkedin.com](http://linkedin.com). Создаете себе профиль, добавляете друзей. В профиле пишете, что хотите работать <нужная страна>/<хотелки>.

Дальше, идете на [SO](stackoverflow.com), так активно участвуете, отвечаете на вопросы, на http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ заполняете профиль.

Параллельно идете на [github](github.com) и выкладываете немного своего кода, прикладываете к профилям. Потенциальный работодатель хотел бы посмотреть Ваш код.

Также идете на [Glass Door](http://www.glassdoor.com/) - чудный сайт, где можно посмотреть среднюю зарплату по компаниям, условия работы и так далее.

Теперь почти все готово и скорее всего head hanter'ы начнут названивать/писать и предлагать. И здесь самое время подучивать иностранные языки. Английский как всегда актуальный, но если хочется жить и работать не в англоязычной стране, то следует и нужный язык подучить, хотя бы базу.

Если профиль заполнен, кода выложено много, а никто не пишет - время поискать самому, например на сайте [Monster](http://www.monster.com/). Некоторые компании (Майкрософт к примеру) часто проводят "выездные" собеседования (Майкрософт делает их регулярно в Москве. И это реальный способ попасть в штаты с последующей гринкартой).

Если хочется почитать, как люди это делают, можно почитать на [rsdn - Заграница](http://rsdn.ru/forum/abroad/)  и [о работе](http://rsdn.ru/forum/job/), и конечно же на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/hub/hr/).